# Seagate hardisk clicking and suspending access, but Seatools passes all tests. How to RMA

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

The drive access will periodically hang for 10-20 seconds at a time, it always gets there in the end but there's no doubt that the drive's on the way out.
Will I have to wait for it to *actually* fail before I send it in, or can I send it in now?
I'm not worried about the data as it's all backed up already, but it's annoying to have this half-dead drive just waiting to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/seatools/seatools-test-codes.html

use the appropriate code from there